# ThreeJS multiple Texture with ShaderMaterial problem on iOS

Tags: javascript, ios, three.js, shader, fragment-shader

I need an help with shaders in Threejs.
I've a plane where i must have a mixing between 10 different texture; now I use ShaderMaterial and I pass all textures that next are used for combining. Here my Fragment Shader code

```
vec3 CFull = texture2D(tFull, vUv).rgb;
vec3 CIndustria = texture2D(tIndustria, vUv ).rgb;
vec3 CCave = texture2D(tCave, vUv).rgb;
vec3 CRifiuti = texture2D(tRifiuti, vUv).rgb;
vec3 CEdile = texture2D(tEdile, vUv).rgb;
vec3 CEventi = texture2D(tEventi, vUv).rgb;
vec3 CMarine = texture2D(tMarine, vUv).rgb;
vec3 COil = texture2D(tOil, vUv).rgb;
vec3 CStrade = texture2D(tStrade, vUv).rgb;
vec3 CVerde = texture2D(tVerde, vUv).rgb; 

c = CFull * CIndustria * CCave * CRifiuti * CEdile * CEventi * CMarine * COil * CStrade * CVerde;
gl_FragColor = vec4(c, 1.0);
```

It works well on Android or desktop but in iOS not work.
If i use only 4/5 texture it works also in iOS...

Maybe it doesn't work because is too heavy?
Do you have any tips to optimize my code? (or other solutions)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WebGL spec [requires the browser to support *at least* 8 combined texture units](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebGL_API/WebGL_best_practices#understand_system_limits). I presume your iOS device meets that minimum requirement of 8, but you're requesting 10.

You can visit [webglreport.com](https://webglreport.com/) on your iOS device and look for "Textures > Max Combined Texture Image Units" to see what its maximum support is. For example, my desktop allows up to 32, but my iPhone's limit is lower.

[image]

If all you're doing to the textures is multiplying them together, you could use a 2D `<canvas>` context, blend them together there, then use [`THREE.CanvasTexture`](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html?q=canvas#api/en/textures/CanvasTexture) to convert the layered canvas into a single texture you can use in Three.js